# XEmacs printing on Windows

Tags: emacs, xemacs

I'd like to improve the printed quality from within Xemacs on my windows machine. For the most part the pretty printing is really great, but I think the code syntax highlighting colours I've chosen don't translate well to black and white printing (in that the code seems faint, and isn't very comfortable to read).

So can I disable the syntax highlighting for printed output (and possibly drop the font size)?

Many thanks

Comment: Emacs 23 has the two functions `ps-print-buffer` and `ps-print-buffer-with-faces`. The first is for black and white.

Comment: thanks for the response, sounds like exactly what I need...BUT my current installation is 21.4.22 - any way to do it in that version?

Comment: You could try [Enscript](http://www.gnu.org/software/enscript/) via shell-command (M-!).

Comment: I had the same issue and can confirm using ps-print-buffer instead of ps-print-bufer-with-faces solved the problem using 23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple and extremely crude solution is obviously to disable the syntax highlight in the window prior to printing